# Should i create custom class for every Recycler View Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to the android development and I use recycler view frequently. Now the data for the recycler comes from backend server in JSON Response. And near about every recycler view in my current have different data. And all the recycler view have more than 4-5 data, for example on one recycler view I have a name, price, quantity on another recycler I have notification type, its icon and so more. So until now for every recycler view, I created a model class with getter and setter and add that class type in an array list and send it to the adapter. But I am seeing that the number of models class is increasing. So my question is that is there any way from which I can solve this problem of creating class again and again. I am new to android development so make my concepts clear, please

Comment: Are your view holders the same for all adapters?

Answer (score 0):

in same xml of class if you have more than one recycler view then create different different adapter in same class, no need to create different different class for every recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes in otherwise you cant bind your data.**

**Using a `RecyclerView` has the following key steps:**

```
 1.Add RecyclerView support library to the gradle build file

 2.Define a **model class** to use as the data source

 3.Add a RecyclerView to your activity to display the items

 4.Create a custom row layout XML file to visualize the item

 5.Create a RecyclerView.Adapter and ViewHolder to render the item

 6.Bind the adapter to the data source to populate the RecyclerView
```

Every adapter has three primary methods: `onCreateViewHolder` to inflate the item layout and create the holder, `onBindViewHolder` to set the view attributes based on the data and `getItemCount` to determine the number of items.